# How do I find my IAM principal ARN, or userID, inside an ECS/Fargate container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

When dealing with S3 bucket policies, and other IAM-related policies in AWS, you sometimes want to allow or deny based on a Principal. However, when you have an ECS task with a Task Role, it is not obvious what your Principal is when the task is actually running.

I struggled with this for several hours, with neither the AWS documentation nor google/Stack Overflow providing much assistance, so I wanted to write up my findings for future strugglers like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use get-caller-identity**

When your ECS container is running, you can invoke the STS function [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) to retrieve information about your current IAM details.

It will return, among other things:

- Your 'arn', something like `arn:aws:sts::#########:assumed-role/YourRoleName/[uuid representing the ECS container ID]` . Note that the bit at the end is a dynamic uuid, not something constant like, for example, `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`
- Your '[UserId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids)', something like `AROA###############:[uuid representing the ECS container ID]`.

(Note: you will need to call this as part of the code that your container runs, and will need to log the output, so that you can see it.)

(Note: this will work in other AWS places, such as the CLI, etc, to give you your arn and UserID)

**Policies using Principals**

The `Principal` for an ECS container is the `arn` value you get from `get-caller-identity`.

If you need to specify a principal in your policy, you might try to write something like this:

```
"Statement": [
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": [
        "arn:aws:sts::########:assumed-role/YourRoleName/*"
      ]
    }
    // statement continues...
```

(The wildcard is because the uuid at the end of the arn is different for each container.)

However, **that won't work**. Principals can be `"*"`, but they otherwise can't contain wildcards. (Seems crazy to me... but apparently it's true: [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/explicit-deny-principal-elements-s3/), [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/))

That means you won't be able to refer to your role by its arn, as the trailing uuid always changes.

However, as explained in those linked articles, you can use `Condition`, `StringLike`, and `aws:userid` instead.

(Unfortunately, these 'Conditions' don't allow you to reference the Principal / arn, only the UserID and a [few other bits of information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse).)

The UserID is returned (by that name) from `get-caller-identity`.

So, a policy statement might end up looking like this:

```
"Statement": [
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Condition": {
      "StringLike": {
        "aws:userid": "AROA##############:*"
      }
    }
    // statement continues...
```

This also works for the inverse, where you want to `DENY` except where `StringNotLike`.